# Create Dictionary after SelectMany

Tags: c#

I have the classes Category and CategoryI18N:

```
public class Category {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }    
  public virtual ICollection<CategoryI18N> CategoriesI18N { get; set; };    
}

public class CategoryI18N {
  public String LanguageCode { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }   
}
```

And I have the following query:

```
IList<Category> categories = service.GetCategories();  

var result = categories.SelectMany(y => y.CategoriesI18N, (c, cI18N) => new { c, cI18N })
```

I would like result to be a `List<Dictionary<String, CategoryI18N>>` where:
1 - The list is the list of categories;
2 - The dictionary values are the `CategoriesI18N` in each `Category` and the Key is each `CategoryI18N` language code.

How should I do this after the `SelectMany`?

Comment: Have you come across the `ToDictionary` linq method? IF not it should be just what you need!

Comment: @Chris: That won't make a `List<Dictionary>`

Comment: @SLaks: That is true but we have the list already. I've put an answer down now anyway to expand on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
categories.Select(x=>x.CategoriesI18N.ToDictionary(y=>y.LanguageCode)).ToList()
```

The `Select` will mean it will make one entry in the final list for each catgegory.

We then transform the category to a dictionary by using `ToDictionary` on its `CategoriesI18N` property. We pass in a simple selector to define the key for each entry. Since we provide no selector for the value it will put the object ie the `CategoriesI18N` entry) as the value in the dictionary.

I'm not sure how the LanguageCode is defined in your `CategoriesI18N` object so you may need to edit that.

Note that I have not used `SelectMany` - this is because it loses the information we want which is the categories. It will instead put all of the CategoriesI18N into a single list which will make it much harder to then put it in a list based on categories.